# Google polymer (paper-drawer-toggle)

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

Paper-drawer-toggle is used when the layout is small (minimized). Please help me use the same option when the layout is wide.

I am using Google Polymer 1.0, HTML and CSS.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code so far?

Comment: Could you please add more descriptive language to the question that clarifies more precisely what you want to accomplish? And what response you get instead.

Comment: Hey, i got answer for my query, need to add <paper-drawer-panel responsive-width="2500px"> than it works for wide layout.

Comment: @Varsha -- cheers for that, i was putting that in the  (<body ...) and wandering why the heck the panel was opening  in wide mode :))  down below there is (Answer you own Question) put that in there so other people know if they have same issue

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `force-narrow` attribute.

```
<paper-drawer-panel id="riotnav-drawer" force-narrow="true">
</paper-drawer-panel>
```